# Spring MVC does not save to database from html form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hello I have build a simple form which should save the data to database however when I submit the form the data is not saved. How would I resolve this ?

form in jsp

```
<form method="post">
    Product Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="productName" name="product name">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="productSerial" name="serial number">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveNewContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveContact(@RequestParam("productName") String productName,@RequestParam("productSerial") int productSerial) {

        Product product = new Product();

        product.setName(productName);
        product.setSerial(productSerial);

        ProductDao.saveNewProduct(product);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

DAO implementation

```
public void saveNewProduct(Product product) {

    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    String sql = "INSERT INTO product (name, serial)"
                  + " VALUES (?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, product.getName(), product.getSerial());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have anything in your view that tells the controller what fields in your JSP file correspond to your model. You can accomplish this by using [Spring form tags](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:form method="post">
    Product Name:<br>
    <form:input type="text" id="productName" name="product name" path="productName" />
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <form:input type="text" id="productSerial" name="serial number" path="productSerial" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

Comment: Hmm now I am getting the following error `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name `

Comment: [See this for the proper way to set up a Spring MVC form with JSP.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/). You are missing some key things like a proper model, a bindingresult, and `modelAttribute` in your form.

Answer (score 0):

to save form in DB use @ModelAtribute(your table) + you need to define data what you want to add in DB somting like :

```
model.addAttribute('productName', productName)
```